# iOS - Show Separator in empty cells of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I am displaying my data in UITableView. For example if i have 2-3 rows, rest of the cells seperator is not shown.

[image]

It displays 2 empty rows and then rest is blank (Gray Area). I need to **show** cell separator in all empty rows. How can i achieve this?

**Note:** I am using storyboard and Prototype Cell and in table created through coding Lines are displaying on empty cells.

Comment: cell separator line is already there, which separator you are talking about?

Comment: click on simulator and click  cmd+1 and check, separators are already visible.

Comment: Yes the seperator are visible on cell that have data. But only 2 empty cells are showing seperator. Rest is blank WHITE

Comment: @saif i am not using simulator

Comment: How many rows you are returning from `tableView numberOfRowsInSection` method?

Comment: what do you mean by separator, the horizontal light gray line, right?, Please attach one more image highlighting the separator

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary Are you using default tableView seperator

Comment: its default seperator of tableview or you had make custom seperator..?

Comment: @RonakChaniyara I have only 2 rows

Comment: @AshokLondhe Yes i am using default seperator

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary then it should show the separator for all cells. if think may have done something wrong. And in your screenshot the separator line are showing for every cell.

Comment: it looks like problem of frame.. check frame of your tableview

Comment: @SunnyShah the background of table is set to gray and the empty gray area is actually table view

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary Try this code: UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];/// change size as you need.
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];// you can also put image here
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

Comment: No this doesn't help either. Maybe it is something related to storyboard TableView prototype cell. But i can't figure out the problem yet

Comment: I tried creating UITableView through code and it is displaying seperators in all empty cells. But the tableView created through Storyboard is no even showing single seperator is i remove the datasource and delegate from my Class.

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary I have sample example on git. Please go through the link https://github.com/Ashoklondhe/SampleTableView

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks all for your Help. It seems i mistakingly added another table as a subview of my Tableview in StoryBoard or the prototype cell that i added initially was not removed (might be some problem with xcode). And that caused that unusual behavior of not showing the separators in empty rows.

Comment: Before Disliking my answer and Question just know that this scenario is real and occurred because of prototype cell and can occur to anyone and this answer would have helped them

Comment: Sometimes in xib, when you drag a UITableView and resize it. It creates two Tables. That caused the problem

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple... add below code in `viewDiodLoad`

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.tableView.tableFooterView.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: it removes last two empty rows i.e. footer but still no seperator is visible just blank space

Answer (score 0):

There's something else going on here - all of the separators should always be visible unless you explicitly hide them.

As @saif said in the comments. If you're using the simulator, the scaling is not very good, so make sure you're using the simulator on 100% mode. The shortcut for this is "CMD+1".

If that is not the solution, then perhaps the frame of your UITableView is incorrect? Press the "Debug View Hierarchy" button to see the frame of your UITableView.
[image: Debug View Hierarchy]

**EDIT:**

When you want to hide the separators on empty cells, you use the following:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

I take it that you're not doing anything like this?

Comment: I checked by setting background color to gray the frame is set just fine and i am testing on device

Comment: i have to show separators on empty cells not hide them. I can hide them already the problem is to show separator on empty cell

Comment: Is your table view vertically sized fully so as to cover the entire parent view vertically? Why is there a gray space below the empty cells? Are the 3 populated rows in the image above part of the table itself?

Answer (score 0):

You have already use custom cell with separator view.

You can do this with the UITableView property separatorStyle. Make sure the property is set to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone and you're set.

```
    Obj-C

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone

    In Swift

    tableView.separatorStyle = .None
```